# atom command line stop working after restart

Tags: shell, atom-editor

Every time I restart my computer, the shell commands for atom stop working and I get zsh command not found, and if I run ln -s /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh /usr/local/bin/atom it says file already exists.

I'm running it from the Applications folder, so the answer that I keep getting to move it from downloads to applications isn't right. Does anyone know what I can do so that I don't have to install shell commands every time I turn my computer off? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you reinstall the software as I was facing almost the same issue: ie. my atom was not able to recognise shell commands after system restart and also there was  no folder `/Applications/Atom.app`. I reinstalled it and now it works. I am on macOS sierra. Hope this helps